# How to load data.txt from MySQL into MATLAB

Tags: php, mysql, matlab

I have a field data in .txt format with the value at MATLAB Workspace of 495X5 double.
i have uploaded the data in .txt fro example, data1.txt onto the mysql database.
I need to import the file from the mysql database for data processing.

Initially, i put the data1.txt at the directory with the .m function folder, the data loaded by

> load 'data1.txt'

Now, I'm needed to load through the mysql database.. can anyone help me with this ?

thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect MySQL to MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110522/connect-mysql-to-matlab)

Comment: thanks for ur reply but, i got connected to the database. but can't go further by loading the file...