# Set up a JDBC connection from Matlab to MySQL on osX

Tags: mysql, macos, matlab, jdbc

I have set up MATLAB (2016b 64-bit) to interact with the local MySQL server. I followed the instructions and created a javaclasspath.txt file on Matlab's `prefdir` location where I saved the mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar location. 
Afterwards, I used the native Matlab Database Explorer App to set up a connection, where after following the steps Matlab created a .mat file on the current folder (see picture):

[image]

As you can see above the .mat file contains a cell array with the listed inputs. 
My question is the following, now that I have successfully set up the server I want to create a "conn = database()" variable. How can I do that? I have read the [Matlab guide](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html#btcmn02) and this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110522/connect-mysql-to-matlab) on Stackoverflow but I get an error "Invalid connection" when I [execute](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/exporting-data-using-bulk-insert.html):

```
conn = database('Data_Science', 'root', '*****', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Data_Science?useSSL=false');


e = exec(conn,['create table BULKTEST (salary decimal, '...
   'player varchar(25), signed_date varchar(25), '...
   'team varchar(25))']);
```

Is something wrong with my code above? Did I write the information wrong? The second part (e) is c/p from Matlab's site. So my doubts are about conn.

UPDATE: When I try the command isoprene(conn) returns a '0'. I still don't get why I can connect properly through the Database Explorer but not through the conn command.

UPDATE: More photos where I show the database plus the Matlab Database Explorer App

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried connecting to DB from somewhere else? e.g. MySQL workbench on the same computer Matlab is. Also, does Data_Science database exist?

Comment: Yeah, I have created a local database named Data_Science. I have updated the information, please have a look. I really do not know what to do here.

Comment: Try `database(host,user,pwd)` only...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried that. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was with my code, specifically with the 'conn' command.

When I used this code, without including the ?useSSL=false :

```
conn = database('Data_Science', 'root', '*****', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Data_Science');
```

I received this warning:

```
Fri Feb 10 13:48:03 GMT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL
5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established 
by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing
applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to
'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false,
or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

So I looked online and the solution was to include ?useSSL=false at the end of conn. Indeed, this worked as I no longer received any further warnings, but when I checked the conn on workspace there was a line with the following message:

```
The connection property 'useSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true',
 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'falseData_Science' is not in this set.
```

Which I never noticed before, and in fact this is what was causing the connection error. So I just reversed back to the original conn, amending the ?useSSL=false change I made. Now, I still receive the warning but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using & at the end:
conn = database('Data_Science', 'root', '*****', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Data_Science?useSSL=false&')